# Qt scene item group bounding rect did not follow rotation

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

As title clues, I tried to rotate group bounding rect by rotating the group itself nor by iteration of child items.

Do I need some kind of refresh for group to boundig rect adjust the shape as the view shows it?

Snippet for PySide :

```
R1 = scene.addRect(itemGroup.boundingRect())
R1.setPos(itemGroup.pos())

scene.addRect(itemGroup.boundingR())

# case 1 - Rotate group through iteration
for item in itemGroup.childItems() :
    item.rotate(90)

# case 2 - Rotete whole group
itemGroup.rotate(90)

R2 = scene.addRect(itemGroup.boundingRect())
R2.setPos(itemGroup.pos())
```

Comment: I dont't know if this is linked to your probem, but you should probably use QGraphicsRectItem( http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsrectitem.html ) instead of using "addRect". The graphics item class is more robust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because bounding rect in your case is local to an item, so rotation is not changing it. you should map rect to scene to get rect position in global coordinates

Comment: +1, but please, can you explain what is main purpose of mapping...any link with example.

Comment: Well, it's general idea around whole QT GraphicsView infrastructure.. although sometimes it leads to pretty weird results.. Any GraphicsViewItem has a position, and this position is relative to parent (if item has a parent) or to scene if it's a 'top level' item. Every item can be transformed (means rotated, scaled or shifted) relative to it's parent. Lets say you have a rectangle with rect (0,0,100,100). And it has a position at (Scene global) (100,100), so after you apply a rotate transform it will be rotated around _its_ (0,0), but it still have (0,0,100,100) dimensions.